# VS Code autocomplete for LWC only shows up when using ctrl+space and not as I type

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, vs-code

I am setting up my LWC dev environment with vscode but for some reason the intellisense for LWC only works if I hit ctrl + space, instead of showing up as I type.

Here's what it look likes as I type:

[image: autocomplete without shortcut]

Here's what it looks like if I hit ctrl + space:

[image: autocomplete with shortcut]

Interestingly enough, this only happens in .html files. Autocompletion in .js files works fine.

I've already tried reinstalling the SF extension pack and reloading VS code multiple times.

Help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to cover bases, is the JavaScript > Suggest setting in VSCode set to "Enabled"?

Comment: @nbrown I have. I've tried on two different machines. I'm starting to think this is the way the extensions behave (which is not good IMO). Thanks!

Comment: Looks like that's just the way it works for now. Following link seems to have a response from SF regarding the same: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/2455.

Comment: @arut ah, bummer. Submit as an answer and claim your bounty good sir. Thanks!

Comment: Other than pointing out the existing limitation, neither my comment solves the problem nor provide a workaround. So, its OK.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your component via the right click context menu in VS Code? It's possible that there's a missing configuration file either among the component files or in your local project. Try recreating the component through that method and make sure the files are saved locally.

[image: VS Code LWC Create Menu]

Comment: I did create it with the context menu. It's weird that it only breaks for html files. Thanks for replying!